# Automatic upload of Application in Apple Store

Tags: ios, upload, app-store

A client asked me to develop a Web application (like php) that is able to upload automatically  an application developed for `iOS` in the Apple store (for example a server-side cron function)
I have seen that is possible with `xcode`, but I have not understand if it is really feasible, and if it is necessary to have a `Mac` that will deal.

Someone more experienced who can give me an opinion?

Comment: An iOS app that automatically uploads another one? A Mac app that automatically uploads an iOS app? A windows app that automatically uploads an iOS app? A web page that automatically uploads an iOS app?

Comment: I don't understand. They want you to develop and (iOS or OSX) application that can do what? Create and upload another iOS application? Please clarify.

Comment: A website that upload an ios app on Apple Store